# how to sort lines on a spreadsheet by date, with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to sort this sheet by date from the column I :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oqQOJkxKoW4UzUhN5j1yuH3FdxLQidIQ3KuzYWviUSs/edit#gid=1544632730

the problem is that only the "title" line have a date in the column I, I wanted the next line after the title and before the next title to be sort in one block.

I have start a code :

```
function myFunction() {
var REA_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1_REALISATION PROJETS");
var lastRowOfData = REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumnOfData = REA_PROJsheet.getLastColumn();
var firstRowOfData = 2;
var sortColumnNumber = 9;
var range = REA_PROJsheet.getRange(firstRowOfData, 1, lastRowOfData - firstRowOfData + 1, lastColumnOfData);// Set the range to sort
  
 
  //commande sort
  range.sort({column: sortColumnNumber, ascending: true});// Sort!
}
```

but of course, it only sort the line that have an info on the column I.

What I whish is that :

[image]

thanks for your help

edit for @COOPER

| COL 01 | COL 02 | COL 03 | COL 04 | COL 05 | COL 06 | COL 07 | COL 08 | COL 09 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 9 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 6 | 9 |
| 1/1/2001 | 9 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 6 | 9 |
| 1/1/2002 | 2 | 6 | 10 | 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| 1/1/2003 | 4 | 1 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 10 | 3 |
|  | 4 | 1 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 10 | 3 |
| 1/1/2004 | 2 | 10 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 10 |
| 1/1/2007 | 9 | 2 | 9 | 9 | 0 | 4 | 10 | 10 |
| 1/1/2009 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 0 |
| 1/1/2012 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
|  | 6 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
|  | 6 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 1/1/2005 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 9 |
| 1/1/2006 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 1 |
| 1/1/2008 | 8 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 4 | 9 |
| 1/1/2010 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 0 |
|  | 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 0 |
|  | 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 0 |
|  | 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 0 |
|  | 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortlines() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dateColumn = 1;
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const ls = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().sort((a,b) => {
    return new Date(a[dateColumn -1]).valueOf() - new Date(b[dateColumn - 1]).valueOf()
  });
  sh.getRange(2,1,ls.length,ls[0].length).setValues(ls);
}
```

Script Test:

Data Before:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| 2 | 1/1/2001 | 9 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 6 | 9 | 2 |
| 3 | 1/1/2002 | 4 | 1 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 10 | 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 1/1/2003 | 2 | 6 | 10 | 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 10 |
| 5 | 1/1/2004 | 2 | 10 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 10 | 0 |
| 6 | 1/1/2005 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 9 |
| 7 | 1/1/2006 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 1/1/2007 | 9 | 2 | 9 | 9 | 0 | 4 | 10 | 10 | 9 |
| 9 | 1/1/2008 | 8 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 4 | 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 1/1/2009 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 1/1/2010 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 1/1/2011 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 0 |

Data After:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| 2 | 1/1/2011 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 0 |
| 3 | 1/1/2010 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1/1/2009 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1/1/2008 | 8 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 4 | 9 | 4 |
| 6 | 1/1/2007 | 9 | 2 | 9 | 9 | 0 | 4 | 10 | 10 | 9 |
| 7 | 1/1/2006 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 1/1/2005 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 9 |
| 9 | 1/1/2004 | 2 | 10 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 10 | 0 |
| 10 | 1/1/2003 | 2 | 6 | 10 | 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 10 |
| 11 | 1/1/2002 | 4 | 1 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 10 | 3 | 7 |
| 12 | 1/1/2001 | 9 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 6 | 9 | 2 |

Code Tested:

```
function mydunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dateColumn = 1;
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const ls = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().sort((a,b) => {
    return new Date(b[dateColumn -1]).valueOf() - new Date(a[dateColumn - 1]).valueOf()
  });
  sh.getRange(2,1,ls.length,ls[0].length).setValues(ls);
}
```

I changed the code slight so that it would sort descending

requested modification:

```
function sortlines() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dateColumn = 1;
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const lr = sh.getLastRow();
  const ls = sh.getRange(2,1,lr - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => r[0] != '').sort((a,b) => {
    return new Date(a[dateColumn -1]).valueOf() - new Date(b[dateColumn - 1]).valueOf()
  });
  sh.getRange(2,1,lr - 1,ls[0].length).clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  sh.getRange(2,1,ls.length,ls[0].length).setValues(ls);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but the code don't seems to work that well. It only "sort" the 10 last lines, and the result of this sorting is not good...

Comment: Please provide me with a table of data that I can copy.  Note I do not follow links to other peoples accounts

Comment: I just  tested it with some of my data and it works fine.

Comment: thanks @Cooper, I guess that my question wasn't that clear, because my purpose was to be able to sort "groups" of data where only the first line have a date. I made a quick edit of my first question with a table that is less or more the kind of data I wanted to sort.

Comment: You can't imagine how luch I will appreciate your help if you have one minute ! thanks